# How to get the Oauth accessToken and OAuth secret for authentication to Twitter in Unity C# using Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

This code was taken from the documentation on Firebases site, I'm just trying to figure out how to make a simple twitter login for Unity 3D.

On the site, the first step is to Authenticating with Firebase is to follow the instructions for Android but it's all in JS and not in C#, to get the OAuth access Token and OAuth Secret.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase.Auth;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TwitterLoginActivity : MonoBehaviour {
private FirebaseAuth auth;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    Firebase.Auth.Credential credential =
    Firebase.Auth.TwitterAuthProvider.GetCredential(accessToken, secret);
    auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
            newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you sould integrate twitter sdk to your unity project.

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth

it seems to be twitter doesnt have sdk for unity,
you should use RESTFUL service for that.